# How to enable Apache SSL Reverse Proxy on HTTP application

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy

I've been having problems attempting to implement a reverse SSL proxy on Apache for an HTTP application on Ubuntu 14.04. As a baseline, the application works fine when I access it via port 8000 in the browser normally. For all intents and purposes, let's say the IP of my app is 192.141.56.11 (I do not have a domain name yet). The application runs with HTTP Basic Auth, I don't know if it's relevant. Basically I'm fishing for some glaring error here and would be grateful if you could help me out. Here is a log of my process:

I created my SSL cert and key and put them in the following locations:

```
/etc/apache/ssl/apache.crt (I performed chmod 644 here)
/etc/apache/ssl/apache.key (I performed chmod 400 here)
```

I then installed:

```
apt-get install apache2
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod ssl
a2enmod proxy_http
```

I then disabled the default config with:

```
a2dissite 000-default
```

I created the file "/etc/apache2/sites-available/redirect.conf"

I then created the file "/etc/apache2/sites-available/redirect.conf" and copied the text below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect "/" "https://192.141.56.11"
</VirtualHost>
```

After, I created the file "/etc/apache2/sites-available/reverse_proxy.conf" and copied below:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache/ssl/apache.key
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

and did:

```
service apache2 restart
```

I now attempt to access the UI of the application on another machine in the Chrome browser. When trying:

```
https://192.141.56.11
```

I get a general SSL connection error.

However, trying

```
http://192.141.56.11:8000
```

gives me the application, as if none of my config changed anything. However,

```
192.141.56.11:80
```

gives me an "Index Of" page with an html folder that says "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.141.56.11 Port 80"

```
192.141.56.11:443
```

gives me the same result except with "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.141.56.11 Port 443"

I've tried all manners of configurations but can't get what I want -- any ideas here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I tried https[:]//192.141.56.11  and got a more specific SSL error:

```
received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

EDIT2: After running apache, I get this warning;

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain        name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

I suppose this is fine as I am using an IP and not a domain name.

EDIT3: It turns out I needed to do:

```
a2ensite reverse_proxy.conf.
```

Now https[:]//192.141.56.11 works but defaults to an apache page. working on this.

EDIT4: I had to do
    a2dissite default-ssl.conf

Now It actually redirects to the app on https[:]//192.141.56.11!! But I can still access the app via port 8000, which is bad {still working on}

EDIT5: IN the end, I couldn't figure out how to block access to the original app via port 8000 on Apache. Instead, I just implemented iptables on the server so that it can only be accessed via HTTPS. This is probably not the correct method. but all I could think of.